# Are there any sites out there that have reviews of well designed sites?

Tags: website-design, critique

I'm just getting started learning design, so I'd love to find a good website that has critiques of "modern" sites. In every book I've seen, screenshots are all taken from very basic sites. I'm imagining this is to keep you focused on the basics of the design rather than the Photoshop mastery of the designer.

Are there any sites out there that have reviews of well designed sites from the past year or so? Sites like Carsonified or Hipmunk would be examples of what I think are "well designed".

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about full in-depth reviews but the following are great resources for well designed material.

- [CSS AWARDS](http://www.cssawards.net/)
- [Awwwards](http://www.awwwards.com/)
- [CSS Design Awards](http://www.cssdesignawards.com/)

Answer (score 2):

[PleaseCritiqueMe.com](http://PleaseCritiqueMe.com) might have what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

webdesign.tutsplus.net Has a periodical user submitted page for review.They also have many tutorials and articles on how to make well designed sites.

Otherwise good old webpagesthatsuck . com has a massive list spanning years explaining what not to do in web design! Googling good web design etc also yields some great results.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

The [Favorite Web Awards](http://www.thefwa.com/) site, which features sites considered well-designed, and [StyleBoost.com](http://styleboost.com/). These are showcase sites, rather than critique sites, but the comments are occasionally useful.